# Update statement with a join and min

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a workflow.procedures table that I need to update with values from a workflow.events table based on a common procedure_id column that lives in both tables. One procedure has many events, and I need to select the row from the events table that has the lowest value in its event_id column. The two tables look something like this:

```
workflow.procedures
procedure_id, default_event_ref
1
2
3

workflow.events
procedure_id, event_id, event_ref
1             1         ref_a
1             2         ref_b
2             3         ref_c
2             4         ref_d
3             5         ref_e
3             6         ref_f
```

After the update, the procedures table should look like this:

```
procedure_id, default_event_ref
1             ref_a
2             ref_c
3             ref_e
```

I am looking at statements similar to this one below, but i'm unsure how to state that we need to look at the min value in the event_id column to determine the correct row since there is a one to many relationship.

```
UPDATE workflow.procedures 
SET default_event_ref = EVENT.event_ref
FROM workflow.procedures PRO 
INNER JOIN workflow.events EVENT 
ON PRO.procedure_id = EVENT.procedure_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is to update the default_event_ref to equal the 'event_ref' of the minimum 'event_id' in the 'workflow.events' table for each 'procedure_id' (pk) in the 'workflow.procedures' table.  Something like this

```
update pro
set default_event_ref = evr.event_ref
from workflow.procedures pro
     cross apply (select top 1 event_ref
                  from workflow.events ev
                  where ev.procedure_id = pro.procedure_id
                  order by event_id) evr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, you have to define a rule to update, I choose MIN in the example below because it fits your example. Maybe you have to adapt for an other choice.

```
UPDATE workflow.procedures 
SET default_event_ref = EVENT.event_ref
FROM workflow.procedures PRO 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT procedure_id, MIN(even_ref) AS event_ref) FROM workflow.events GROUP BY procedure_id) EVENT 
ON PRO.procedure_id = EVENT.procedure_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Pid INT
SET @Pid = (SELECT MIN(procedure_id) FROM workflow.procedures)

WHILE @Pid <= (SELECT MAX(procedure_id) FROM workflow.procedures)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE workflow.procedures
    SET default_event_ref  = 
        (SELECT aa.event_ref FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY procedure_id ORDER BY procedure_id, event_id)  AS rownb
            FROM workflow.events) aa
        WHERE  aa.rownb= 1
        AND aa.procedure_id = @Pid)
    WHERE procedure_id  = @Pid
    SET @Pid  =@Pid+1
END;
```